# Element is no longer attached to the DOM, Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Scenario:

1. Select a value in drop down
2. Download the sheet
3. Come out of loop
4. Select 2nd option
5. Download the other sheet

But it is not selecting the second option in the loop and giving this error message:

```
Element is no longer attached to the DOM
Command duration or timeout: 11 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.html
Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:59:12'
System info: host: 'Treselle', ip: '192.168.0.123', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_60'
Session ID: 8b83d2b4-acfd-4bb5-9a07-a4155e98dfc1
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=45.0}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could you post the HTML or a link to the target web?

Comment: sure it is http://www.depreportingservices.state.pa.us/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOil_Gas%2fOil_Gas_Well_Historical_Production_Report

Comment: Please post your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

If the DOM has changed in the first download you need to relocate the dropdown each iteration. You should also wait for the report to appear before looking for the dropdown again

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
int size = 3;

for (int i = 2 ; i < size ; ++i) {
    WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(...);
    Select select = new Select(dropdown);
    size = select.getOptions().size(); //change the condition to the number of options
    select.selectByIndex(i);
    driver.findElement(...).click(); //download the report
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ReportViewerControl_AsyncWait_Wait"))); //wait for the loader to appear
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("ReportViewerControl_AsyncWait_Wait"))); //wait for the loader to disappear
}
```

Comment: but the size of drop down changes everymonth, so numofsheets i cannot giving the exact number there. So what should i replace with numofsheets?

Comment: my o/p is: size:62
The old month is: Sep 2015 (Unconventional wells)
The new month is:Dec 2015 (Unconventional wells)
New Month data downloaded in csv format:Dec 2015 (Unconventional wells)
clicked the next month
The new month is:Oct 2015 (Unconventional wells)
clicked the next month
The new month is:Sep 2015 (Unconventional wells)
No new months are available to download

Comment: it downloads first month in the drop down, but for other months it just prints month's txt and comes out of loop :(

Comment: #1: select a month in drop down, click download #2: come out of loop , select second month in the list then download that month report again, but here it downloads one month report sucessfully but for other months with above fix downloading only one month and printing other month's text. Hope i am clear.

Comment: @user2762008 I edited my answer, I added explicit wait to wait for the loader to disappear so we know the report is loaded and we can choose the next option.

Comment: I also change the initial size to avoid choosing the first two options.

Comment: size:62
The old month is: Sep 2015 (Unconventional wells)
The new month is:Dec 2015 (Unconventional wells)
New Month data downloaded in csv format:Dec 2015 (Unconventional wells)
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.className: WaitText

Comment: this is the o/p i got

Comment: @user2762008 switch in the `wait` `By.className("WaitText")` with `By.id("ReportViewerControl_AsyncWait_Wait")`

Comment: ize:62
The old month is: Sep 2015 (Unconventional wells)
The new month is:Dec 2015 (Unconventional wells)
New Month data downloaded in csv format:Dec 2015 (Unconventional wells)
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 50 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: ReportViewerControl_AsyncWait_Wait

Comment: the above is the o/p i got